# If $ G $ is a finite soluble group and satisfies the permutizer condition, then for any odd prime $ p $, $ G $ is $ p $-supersoluble.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, solvable-groups

If $ G $ is a finite soluble group and satisfies the permutizer condition, then for any odd prime $ p $, $ G $ is $ p $-supersoluble. It is for me problem that why $ G $ can't $ 2 $-supersoluble group. ( If for any proper subgroup $ H $ of $ G $, $ H < P_{G}(H) $ such that $ P_{G}(H)=\langle g\in G \ \vert \langle g \rangle H = H \langle g \rangle \rangle $, then said $ G $ satisfying the permutizer condition.)

Comment: You need to remind readers what all these terms mean. They may be familiar to you, but they won't be to everyone.

Comment: But $G$ can be a 2-supersoluble group. So I do not understand the problem. $S_4$ is an example of a group that satisfies the permutizer condition but is not $2$-supersoluble.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thanks, i understand, Since $ S_{4} $ isn't supersoluble, $ S_{4} $ isn't $ 2 $-supersoluble.

Comment: No that does not follow! Supersoluble implies $2$-supersoluble, but the converse is false. There are groups that are $2$-supersoluble but not supersoluble. The reason that $S_4$ is not $2$-supersoluble is that one of its chief factors has order $4$. In a $2$-supersoluble group, all chief factors must have order $2$ or have odd order.

Comment: @DerekHolt But $ G $  is supersoluble iff $ G $ is $ p $-supersoluble group for any prime $ p $.

Comment: Yes that's right!